# How do I change STDOUT for FFI calls in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ffi

I am accessing a C function in Ruby through FFI.  The function is called `AllocTilts::summary`.

I want the method to not print anything to STDOUT. However my temporary redirect of STDOUT is not working.  Is there something else I can do?

```
puts 'test outside before' #prints successfully
File.open("/var/alloc_tilts/summary_dump", "w") do |out|
  stdout, $stdout = $stdout, out
  puts 'test inside' #doesn't print to STDOUT as expected
  AllocTilts.summary(2012, 2011) #prints undesired stuff to STDOUT
  $stdout = stdout
end
puts 'test outside after' #prints successfully
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do `AllocTilts.summary` write to stdout? If it uses `printf` and you do not have access to its source code there is nothing you can do (short of calling libc `dup`).

The way ruby writes to `$stdout` rather than the real stdout, is

```
# from io.c

rb_funcall2(rb_stdout, rb_intern("puts"), argc, argv);
```

You should use similar code to generate output inside `AllocTilts.summary`.

Comment: Could you go into more detail about `dup`?

Comment: You can play with `dup` to redirect the normal stdout to another file descriptor you created, then redirect from that new file descriptor to Ruby's `$stdout`. You can read about `dup` and stdout redirection at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605130/redirecting-exec-output-to-a-buffer-or-file