# freopen and execvp in c

Tags: c, execvp, freopen

I am doing a minor shell implementation in c, and I am stuck.

I want to be able to redirect `stdin` and `stdout`, but I am confused. In, my shell, when I want to start a program, I use the `execvp` function. Now I would like to be able to redirect `stdout`, so If I run another process, the output should be redirected to a file instead of the screen.

Here is sample code:

```
pid_t pid;

// Child process
pid = vfork();

if((pid == 0)){
    freopen("myfile.txt", "w", stdout);
    char* arr[3];
    arr[0] = "cat";
    arr[1] = "someFileToCat.txt";
    arr[2] = NULL;
   execvp("cat", arr);
   fclose(stdout);
}
```

It does however print in the terminal, and not in the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirecting exec output to a buffer or file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605130/redirecting-exec-output-to-a-buffer-or-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File streams are a `C` abstraction. What you are looking for are lower level system calls such as `open`, `close`, and `dup2`.

See [Redirecting exec output to a buffer or file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605130/redirecting-exec-output-to-a-buffer-or-file) for a full example.