# redirecting output to the text file c#

Tags: c#, redirect

This is my code:

```
Process pr2 = new Process();
pr2.StartInfo.FileName = "show-snps";
pr2.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-Clr -x 2 out.delta > out.snps";
pr2.Start();
pr2.WaitForExit();
```

show-snps writes an error. when I delete the part  "> out.snps" everything is ok and it writes the result into the terminal, but I need to redirect it to the text file.
How can I do this?

Comment: Wrong usage. Suggests to read manual

Comment: But when I copy everything to the command line there is no error

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't redirect like that when you are starting the program like that. It requires a shell such as CMD.EXE to do that.

Instead, you need to set [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) to a stream that you manage yourself.

[There's an example here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput).

That example shows how to get the data that the console process creates via a StreamReader. For your requirement, you would read from that StreamReader and write to a FileStream output.

In case it's any help, here's a utility class I wrote years ago (for .Net 2) which might be instructive:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;


namespace ProcessUtilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Encapsulates an executable program.
    /// This class makes it easy to run a console app and have that app's output appear
    /// in the parent console's window, and to redirect input and output from/to files.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// To use this class:
    /// (1) Create an instance.
    /// (2) Set the ProgramFileName property if a filename wasn't specified in the constructor.
    /// (3) Set other properties if required.
    /// (4) Call Run().
    /// </remarks>

    public class Executable
    {
        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>Runs the specified program file name.</summary>
        /// <param name="programFileName">Name of the program file to run.</param>

        public Executable(string programFileName)
        {
            ProgramFileName = programFileName;

            _processStartInfo.ErrorDialog            = false;
            _processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow         = false;
            _processStartInfo.UseShellExecute        = false;
            _processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            _processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError  = false;
            _processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput  = false;
            _processStartInfo.WindowStyle            = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            _processStartInfo.Arguments              = "";
        }

            /// <summary>Constructor.</summary>

        public Executable(): this(string.Empty)
        {
        }

        #endregion  // Constructor

        #region Public Properties

        /// <summary>The filename (full pathname) of the executable.</summary>

        public string ProgramFileName
        {
            get
            {
                return _processStartInfo.FileName;
            }

            set
            {
                _processStartInfo.FileName = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>The command-line arguments passed to the executable when run. </summary>

        public string Arguments
        {
            get
            {
                return _processStartInfo.Arguments;
            }

            set
            {
                _processStartInfo.Arguments = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>The working directory set for the executable when run.</summary>

        public string WorkingDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                return _processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory;
            }

            set
            {
                _processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The file to be used if standard input is redirected,
        /// or null or string.Empty to not redirect standard input.
        /// </summary>

        public string StandardInputFileName
        {
            set
            {
                _standardInputFileName = value;
                _processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
            }

            get
            {
                return _standardInputFileName;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The file to be used if standard output is redirected,
        /// or null or string.Empty to not redirect standard output.
        /// </summary>

        public string StandardOutputFileName
        {
            set
            {
                _standardOutputFileName = value;
                _processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
            }

            get
            {
                return _standardOutputFileName;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The file to be used if standard error is redirected,
        /// or null or string.Empty to not redirect standard error.
        /// </summary>

        public string StandardErrorFileName
        {
            set
            {
                _standardErrorFileName = value;
                _processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
            }

            get
            {
                return _standardErrorFileName;
            }
        }

        #endregion  // Public Properties

        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>Add a set of name-value pairs into the set of environment variables available to the executable.</summary>
        /// <param name="variables">The name-value pairs to add.</param>

        public void AddEnvironmentVariables(StringDictionary variables)
        {
            if (variables == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("variables");

            StringDictionary environmentVariables = _processStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables;

            foreach (DictionaryEntry e in variables)
                environmentVariables[(string)e.Key] = (string)e.Value;
        }

        /// <summary>Run the executable and wait until the it has terminated.</summary>
        /// <returns>The exit code returned from the executable.</returns>

        public int Run()
        {
            Thread standardInputThread  = null;
            Thread standardOutputThread = null;
            Thread standardErrorThread  = null;

            _standardInput  = null;
            _standardError  = null;
            _standardOutput = null;

            int exitCode = -1;

            try
            {
                using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo = _processStartInfo;
                    process.Start();

                    if (process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput)
                    {
                        _standardInput = process.StandardInput;
                        standardInputThread = startThread(new ThreadStart(supplyStandardInput), "StandardInput");
                    }

                    if (process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError)
                    {
                        _standardError = process.StandardError;
                        standardErrorThread = startThread(new ThreadStart(writeStandardError), "StandardError");
                    }

                    if (process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput)
                    {
                        _standardOutput = process.StandardOutput;
                        standardOutputThread = startThread(new ThreadStart(writeStandardOutput), "StandardOutput");
                    }

                    process.WaitForExit();
                    exitCode = process.ExitCode;
                }
            }

            finally  // Ensure that the threads do not persist beyond the process being run
            {
                if (standardInputThread != null)
                    standardInputThread.Join();

                if (standardOutputThread != null)
                    standardOutputThread.Join();

                if (standardErrorThread != null)
                    standardErrorThread.Join();
            }

            return exitCode;
        }

        #endregion  // Public Methods

        #region Private Methods

        /// <summary>Start a thread.</summary>
        /// <param name="startInfo">start information for this thread</param>
        /// <param name="name">name of the thread</param>
        /// <returns>thread object</returns>

        private static Thread startThread(ThreadStart startInfo, string name)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(startInfo);
            t.IsBackground = true ;
            t.Name = name;
            t.Start();
            return t;
        }

        /// <summary>Thread which supplies standard input from the appropriate file to the running executable.</summary>

        private void supplyStandardInput()
        {
            // feed text from the file a line at a time into the standard input stream

            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(_standardInputFileName))
            using (StreamWriter writer = _standardInput)
            {
                writer.AutoFlush = true;

                for (;;)
                {
                    string textLine = reader.ReadLine();

                    if (textLine == null)
                        break;

                    writer.WriteLine(textLine);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Thread which outputs standard output from the running executable to the appropriate file.</summary>

        private void writeStandardOutput()
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(_standardOutputFileName))
            using (StreamReader reader = _standardOutput)
            {
                writer.AutoFlush = true;

                for (;;)
                {
                    string textLine = reader.ReadLine();

                    if (textLine == null)
                        break;

                    writer.WriteLine(textLine);
                }
            }

            if (File.Exists(_standardOutputFileName))
            {
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(_standardOutputFileName);

                // if the error info is empty or just contains eof etc.

                if (info.Length < 4)
                    info.Delete();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Thread which outputs standard error output from the running executable to the appropriate file.</summary>

        private void writeStandardError()
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(_standardErrorFileName))
            using (StreamReader reader = _standardError)
            {
                writer.AutoFlush = true;

                for (;;)
                {
                    string textLine = reader.ReadLine();

                    if (textLine == null)
                        break;

                    writer.WriteLine(textLine);
                }
            }

            if (File.Exists(_standardErrorFileName))
            {
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(_standardErrorFileName);

                // if the error info is empty or just contains eof etc.

                if (info.Length < 4)
                    info.Delete();
            }
        }

        #endregion  // Private Methods

        #region Private Fields

        private StreamReader _standardError  ;
        private StreamReader _standardOutput ;
        private StreamWriter _standardInput  ;

        private string _standardInputFileName;
        private string _standardOutputFileName;
        private string _standardErrorFileName;

        ProcessStartInfo _processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();


        #endregion  // Private Fields
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Matthew Watson ,  I looked into the class you wrote , One doubt i need to ask , Currently the Run() method waits for the thread to completed , It doesn't return the control back to the calling Thread (Main thread) . How that could be achieved .

Comment: On linux this is supported without using a shell (directly by the kernel). Ex here in C : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605130/redirecting-exec-output-to-a-buffer-or-file
I don't know how it works on Windows

Comment: The example link is broken

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question, but it came up on the first google link for searching for how to redirect the standard output of a launched Process to a file.

The answer I think works well is to add a OutputDataReceived event and write to the file there.

Here is a complete working example.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

class StandardAsyncOutputExample
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        var outputStream = new StreamWriter("output.txt");
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "ipconfig.exe";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                outputStream.WriteLine(e.Data);
            }
        });

        process.Start();
       
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        process.WaitForExit(); 
        process.Close();
       
        outputStream.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It didn't work because `>` redirect was supported by `cmd.exe` shell.  Try the following code instead.

```
Process pr2 = new Process();
pr2.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
pr2.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/k \"show-snps -Clr -x 2 out.delta > out.snps\"";
pr2.Start();
pr2.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: If the Arguments string is declared as Verbatim (with the @ at the start), then you can't escape the double-quote with a slash.  Instead put in two adjacent double-quotes to signify a single.  The example above should be:
@"/k ""show-snps -Clr -x 2 out.delta > out.snps""";

Comment: @erict; I'm having same problem. This solution is enough to run the process. But I want to know the error thrown in the cmd. I've tried to use pr2.StandardError.ReadToEnd().ToString().Split(new[] { ':' })
with RedirectStandardError = true;
So, long there were no errors while executing. But it never stop to return something. 

So, i want to know, how do i read the errors after a command is executed, with cmd.exe /k ""some command here > output.file"". Please help.