# RedirectStandardOutput using C#

Tags: c#, redirectstandardoutput

I want to launch a .exe program using C# and read the values from the cmd generated from the .exe

The .exe launches successfully but I cannot read the values:

This is my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();

start.FileName = (@"D:\BSC\Thesis\Raphael_Thesis\smiledetector\bin\smiledetector.exe");
start.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\BSC\Thesis\Raphael_Thesis\smiledetector\bin\";
start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

//Start the process

using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
{
    // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        textBox1.Text = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you run this code?

Comment: As much as I don't know all the ins and outs of using statements, I'm not sure that you need to have a using statement for a stream that you didn't create I.E. `using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)`

Comment: I've just copied and pasted your code(except I used a different exe to run) and It worked.  Try running it with simple command such as `cmd /c google.com` and see what happens

Comment: Also see my answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256587/redirecting-output-to-the-text-file-c-sharp/16256623#16256623 which provides a sample showing how to redirect input and output and use threading to stop it from blocking.

Comment: Is the process writing to stderr instead?

Answer (score 1):

As Sam I Am has indicated, drop the using block for the `StreamReader`

```
using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
{ 
    string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    textBox1.Text = result;
}
```

Keep in mind however your calling application will block until process completes and all the output can be read.

Comment: There's a reason I didn't post that as an answer.  It's because I copied his code and ran it without an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\BSC\Thesis\Raphael_Thesis\smileDetector\vs2010\smiledetectorDebug";
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\BSC\Thesis\Raphael_Thesis\smileDetector\vs2010\";
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHander);

    p.Start();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

where p is `Process p = new Process();`

```
void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    data.Add(Convert.ToInt32(e.Data));
}
```

where data is a List of int

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any weird thing in your code, it should work fine. Taking a look at the doc, it gives a brief example of how to redirect it:

```
 // Start the child process.
 using(Process p = new Process())
 {
   // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
   p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   p.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\BSC\Thesis\Raphael_Thesis\smiledetector\bin\smiledetector.exe";
   p.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\BSC\Thesis\Raphael_Thesis\smiledetector\bin\";
   p.Start();
   // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
   // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
   // p.WaitForExit();
   // Read the output stream first and then wait.
   string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
   p.WaitForExit();
 }
```

source: [Process.StandardOutput Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)

Comment: can someone guide me to use thread in this code, cause I think I need to read inputs while the cmd is running