# Redirect output using Process in c# with > in ProcessStartInfo.Arguments

Tags: c#, process

I want to redirect output to a file but I don't want to do it through the arguments like so:

```
ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
sInfo.FileName = "test.exe";
sInfo.Arguments = "> test.log";
Process myProc = new Process();
myProc.StartInfo = sInfo;
myProc.Start();
```

It seems if I do that, it just flat out doesn't work. Any ideas how or a way around it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirecting output to the text file c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256587/redirecting-output-to-the-text-file-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a stream reader : start the process first using **ProcessStartInfo** class then use the **RedirectStandardOutput** and put it as a boolean true, now start your process and read your file with **StreamReader**, more help can be found [HERE](http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput).