# Capture 7-Zip output and exit code from a process in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have the following VB.NET 4.0 console application that runs 7z.exe in a process and successfully completes with a zipped file:

```
Public Sub CompressFiles(sZipFileName As String, sDriveLetter As String)

    Dim s7ZipCmdArgs As String = ""
    Dim myProcess As New Process

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Scanning files...")

    'Compress files
    s7ZipCmdArgs = " a -r -y -xr!windows\ -xr!$Recycle.Bin\ " + sZipFileName _
        + " " + sDriveLetter + "\*.txt" _
        + " " + sDriveLetter + "\*.doc" _
        + " " + sDriveLetter + "\*.xls" _
        + " " + sDriveLetter + "\*.ppt" _
        + " " + sDriveLetter + "\*.url" _
        + " " + sDriveLetter + "\*.docx" _
        + " " + sDriveLetter + "\*.xlsx" _
        + " " + sDriveLetter + "\*.pptx" _
        + " " + sDriveLetter + "\*.pdf" _
        + " " + sDriveLetter + "\*.wav" _
        + "> C:\test\zipresults.txt"

    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\test\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = s7ZipCmdArgs
    myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\test"
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    myProcess.Start()
    myProcess.WaitForExit()
End Sub
```

The code executes fine except for the redirect to a text file: "> C:\test\zipresults.txt" in the s7ZipCmdArgs string variable. I'm not sure why that's not working, I've tried different sets of double and triple quotes without success.  It does work in a batch file using the same string.

My second question is: How do I capture the 7Zip exit code so that I can determine if it completed successfully?  It returns the following integers: 0 (No errors), 1 (Non fatal error), 2 (Fatal error), 7 (Command line error), 8 (Memory error), and 255 (User error).  I'm not sure how to capture the integer so that I can decode it.

Comment: I have tried the redirect ">" with spaces on both sides and next to the file definition without success.

Comment: The myProcess.ExitCode method does contain the exit code for the 7Zip application.  Good call.

Comment: It seems that redirecting with `>` does not work from `Process.Start` - I've updated my answer.

Comment: After trying similar tasks with 7z I switched to DotNetZip - much easier.

Comment: The issue I have now is after myProcess.WaitForExit() executes the console output never returns.  When I comment out RedirectStandardOutput = True, it works fine.  Not sure what I'm missing.  As for .NET zip, I was unable to search for all the file types and exclude Windows and the recycle bin.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the event handler for writing the output to a file - see if that helps.  If not, please post your updated code.

Comment: The updated code works perfectly.

Comment: Glad it's working!  I suppose the previous issue was due to the volume of output being too much for some buffer, which I didn't hit in my test.

Comment: I'm not sure where the overflow was occurring, but the code works fine now.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>For the first part, have you tried adding a space before the `>` in your command args?  You could also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/285841/2278086) for capturing the output in code.</strike>

For the first part, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16256623/2278086) you can't redirect the standard output using `>` when using `Process.Start()`.  So, you will need to remove the redirect from the arguments, set `StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` to `true`, and then write the output to a file in the `OutputDataReceived` event.  Something like this:

```
Dim pgm = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
Dim args = "l C:\Dev\Test.zip"
Dim myProcess = New Process()
With myProcess.StartInfo
    .FileName = pgm
    .Arguments = args
    .WorkingDirectory = "C:\Dev"
    .UseShellExecute = False
    .CreateNoWindow = True
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True
End With
Using out = New StreamWriter("C:\Dev\test.txt")
    AddHandler myProcess.OutputDataReceived,
        Sub(sender, e)
            out.WriteLine(e.Data)
        End Sub
    myProcess.Start()
    myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
    myProcess.WaitForExit()
End Using
```

For the second, `myProcess.ExitCode` will have the result after the `WaitForExit()` call.