# Save The Cmd output into txt file in C#

Tags: c#, cmd

How Can i save the CMD Commands into txt file in C#

or how can i display command prompt in C#

here is my code

```
                      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var p = new Process();

        string path = @"C:\Users\Microsoft";
        string argu = "-na>somefile.bat";
        ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo("netstat", argu);
        process.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        process.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.CreateNoWindow = false;

        Process.Start(process);

        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "sr.txt";
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect the standard output:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //
    // Setup the process with the ProcessStartInfo class.
    //
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
    start.FileName = @"C:\7za.exe"; // Specify exe name.
    start.UseShellExecute = false;
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    //
    // Start the process.
    //
    using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
    {
        //
        // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
        //
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(result);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Code is from [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput)

Also look to this answer: [redirecting output to the text file c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16256623/2630261)

Comment: thanx alot , but first of all i want save the result into txt file then show that 1!!

Comment: @user3532929 than have a look at the second link i posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256587/redirecting-output-to-the-text-file-c-sharp/16256623#16256623

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to save output to a text file, using cmd.exe built into Windows:

```cs
using (Process.Start(fileName: "cmd", arguments: "/k \"netstat > output.txt\""))
{

}
```