# Extract thumbnail from .indd file programatically using ExifTool

Tags: c#, process, exiftool

I am trying to extract thumbnail from a indd file using c#.

I can execute the following command from commandline, which works fine

```
exiftool -r -b -PageImage sample.indd > sample.jpg
```

but when I tried it from my c# project its not producing the output file

My sample code

```
string c_arguments = string.Format("-r -b -PageImage {0} > {1}", _DirectoryPath + "\\" +  fileName, 
_DirectoryPath + "\\output.jpg");
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("exiftool.exe", c_arguments);
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

try
{
  using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(psi))
  {
    exeProcess.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Executed successfully");
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Error occured, ErrorMsg: " + ex.Message);
}
```

after exeProcess.Start(), is executed the program waits forever no output is produced.

What am I missing here.

Answer (score 1):

The `> sample.jpg` part of your example command line is a shell redirect and is a function of the shell/terminal/CMD that you are using.  It is not available when starting exiftool from your program (see [this related StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16256623/3525475)).

You might look into the [`-w` (`-textout`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#w-EXT-or-FMT--textOut).  See [this example command](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#exiftool--a--b--W-d-f_-t--c.-s--preview:all-dir), which is more complex than what you need, but should provide help creating the command you need.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, after i removed "> sample.jpg", and added
    exeProcess.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;
the above section, I can get the data, which I then appended in StringBuilder, and got error when i tried
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(stringBuilder.ToString());
says invalid character in Base64 string.

Comment: The output from exiftool would not be in Base64, but the actual jpeg file (binary data).  Is `exeProcess.OutputDataReceived` converting to Base64 for you, required the need to convert it back?  Otherwise, I can't help beyond this because I don't know C#, just exiftool.