# How to mimic Stdin input when running an exe from C# using create process?

Tags: c#, stdin, oggvorbis

I have an audio converter .exe that i want to wrap in a C# program, for UI and inputs etc.
To use the AudioConverter.exe, it is ran from the console with the suffix " < inputFile > ouputFile".
So the full line reads something like

```
C:\\User\Audioconverter.exe < song.wav > song.ogg
```

So far i have been able to start the converter succesfully outside of C#, I have managed to have the converter run via create process in C# in a hang state (without input and output files).
My code in C# thus far is pretty similar to the answers given on this site:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConverterWrapper2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            LaunchCommandLineApp();
        }
        static void LaunchCommandLineApp()
        {
            // For the example
            const string ex1 = "C:\\Users\\AudioConverter.exe";
            const string ex2 = "C:\\Users\\res\\song.wav";
            const string ex3 = "C:\\Users\\out\\song.ogg";

            // Use ProcessStartInfo class
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.FileName = "AudioConverter2.exe";
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            startInfo.Arguments = ex1 + " < " + ex2 + " > " + ex3; \\Process is ran successfully without the addition of input and output files, but hangs waiting for files.

            try
            {
                using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                {
                    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Log error.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far the converter exe hasnt been able to start up correctly, this leads me to ask the question are inputs for stdin different from arguments?

Regardless i need to mimic this style of input and would appreciate any information. I had assumed that i could just pass the input and output files as arguments but i havent had much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
startInfo.Arguments = ex1 + " < " + ex2 + " > " + ex3; \\Process is ran successfully without the addition of input and output files, but hangs waiting for files.
```

That won't work.

`A.exe < B > C` is **not** process `A.exe` called with arguments `< B > C`. It's rather a **shell** instruction to:

- start `A.exe` **without** arguments,
- read file `B` and redirect its contents to the new process' stdin and
- write the new process' stdout to file `C`.

You have two options to do that in C#:

1. You can use the help of the shell, i.e., you can start `cmd.exe` with arguments `/c C:\User\Audioconverter.exe < song.wav > song.ogg` or
2. you can re-implement what the shell is doing in C#. A code example for that can be found in this related question:

   - [redirecting output to the text file c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16256587/87698)

Comment: Well option one works, but im not 100% on whether its smart to use this over the second method. The second will take a little more testing to see if i can impliment it. But thank you.