# How can I pass the redirection operator '>' as an argument for execv?

Tags: c, echo, io-redirection, execv

In the linux terminal, I can type

```
echo hello! > /path/to/file
```

I thought I would be able to do the same thing using execv:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void){
    char *write_cmd[] = { "echo", "hello!", ">", "/path/to/file", NULL};
    if (fork() == 0){
        execv("/bin/echo", write_cmd);
    }
    else{
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, this code doesn't write 'hello!' to the file, which is what I want it to do. Is there another way to do this using execv and echo?

Edit:
I've tried using dup2 as a solution as well:
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
int main(void){
    char *write_cmd[] = { "echo", "hello!", NULL };
    if (fork() == 0){
        int tmpFd = open("/path/to/file", O_WRONLY);
        dup2(tmpFd, 1);
        execv("/bin/echo", write_cmd);
        close(tmpFd);
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, this doesn't give me the result I want either. This writes 'hello!' to the file, but it also overwrites everything else that was already written on the file. How can I guarantee that 'hello!' will be written to the END of the file?

Comment: The shell interprets it as the redirection-operator. As you execute the new program directly instead of asking the shell to do it on your behalf, you get to do the redirection manually. Look at `dup2`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried using dup2. However, the problem is that I want to be able to always write to the END of the file. When I use dup2, I am only able to overwrite what is already written to the file.

Comment: Your  `echo hello! > /path/to/file` overwrites the file. If you always want to append, please update the question to make that clear. The shell uses `>>` to append to a file. If you use what I suggested, you can pass `>>` rather than `>` to the shell.

Comment: the program needs to be executing a shell.,  'echo' is just a command passed to a shell, not a standalone executable.  suggest using 'system( "echo hello! >> /path/to/file" );'  The '>>' appends to the file

Comment: The code in your question will not compile. You're missing a semicolon on the declaration of `write_cmd`, and `'>'` should be `">"`. Please include compilable code in your question (unless you're asking about a compile-time error).

Comment: Your edit is correct, and your note about it overwriting the file is the same as the shell does with `>`.  If you want to append to the file (as the shell does if you use `>>`), open the file with `O_APPEND` in the flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, redirection operators like `>` are interpreted by the shell, and mean nothing to [execve(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) (or to echo, for that matter). You could try using [system(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) instead, or you could set up the redirection yourself by opening the output file and setting standard out to the resulting file descriptor using [dup2(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605130/redirecting-exec-output-to-a-buffer-or-file)).

Secondly, `write_cmd` is an array of `char*`, but `'>'` (note the single quotes) has type `int`. This effectively means that you are putting an integer in an array that otherwise contains pointers to strings. You probably meant to write `">"`.

Comment: [system(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) was the best option. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can, but only indirectly.

The `>` redirection operator is interpreted by the shell; `/bin/echo` doesn't recognize it, and treats it as just another argument to be printed.

If you want the shell to do the redirection, you need to invoke `/bin/sh` and pass the entire command to it as an argument.

Untested code follows:

```
char *write_cmd[] = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo hello! > /path/to/file", NULL };
// ...
execv("/bin/sh", write_cmd);
```

Or, more simply, you could use `system()`.