# how to catch stderr from a failed exec command?

Tags: c, fork, stderr

When failing to launch an `exec` command - I can only get a bad return code from the `exec` - how can I also get the stderr?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    char* argv[] = {"bla", NULL};
    execvp(argv[0], argv);
    printf("exec failed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In this snippet the `printf` is only reached if the `execvp` breaks - which in my case it does. I'm interested in getting the output of the shell for trying to run `bla`:

```
Command 'bla' not found, did you mean:

  command 'tla' from deb tla (1.3.5+dfsg1-2build1)
  command 'bwa' from deb bwa (0.7.17-4)
  command 'bls' from deb bacula-sd (9.4.2-2ubuntu5)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

How can I find it? tried playing with `errno` but didn't find the data I'm looking for

`errno` try:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  char* argv[] = {"bla", NULL};
  execvp(argv[0], argv);
  printf("exec failed\n %d", errno);
  return 0;
}
```

returns 2 - but no info.

2 is "  2   ENOENT            No such file or directory" - but I still want `Bash`'s stderr

Comment: Did you consider to redirect `stderr` in a pipe?

Comment: @thebusybee I have - it seems like the redirection only happens after the process is spawned - so the error of the shell is not captured

Comment: Why `waitpid`? As long as I can see your code is not calling `fork`.

Comment: @DavidRanieri It is a snippet of a bigger piece where I fork, and the child calls exec. I'll delete the waitpid as indeed it is not relevant for this snippet

Comment: Are you exec'ing a shell or are you exec'ing another executable?

Comment: I think exec doesn't rely on the shell, it asks the OS directly, even if the program was started by the shell. If what you want is the output of Bash, then you need to explicitly involve Bash, like `exec bash bla`. But then, provided that Bash is installed, exec will always work. So maybe you need to fork, the child execs Bash and captures STDERR, the parent waits for the child and somehow gets STDERR.

Comment: `execvp` uses the shell's environment PATH, but indeed - you might be the right that I'm not actually invoking the shell itself. If so - then @DavidRanieri's answer is the maximum I can get without actually invoking `execvp("bash", {"bash" "bla", NULL});`

Comment: `execvp` invokes the shell under certain circumstances, at least on some systems. As your observation shows, it is invoked in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `#include <errno.h>`, you can also use `perror()` to get more information about the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* argv[] = {"bla", NULL};

    execvp(argv[0], argv);
    perror("execvp");
    fprintf(stderr, "errno: %d\n", errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Output:

```
execvp: No such file or directory
errno: 2
```

Comment: this gives good information about the error - but not the shell's stderr

Comment: Sorry but then why are you accepting the answer? If it doesn't help you can wait for more suggestions from other users ;)

Comment: see my last comment on the question itself - my understanding is that I don't even invoke the shell - hence I can't get any better stderr than what errno gives me

Answer (score 0):

Search with keywords "c exec stderr", you can get many mature solution.
Here is the top answer.
[stackoverflow - R Samuel Klatchko - Redirecting exec output to a buffer or file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2605313/5628643)